# Retrieving User password in Back4App

Tags: flutter, parse-platform, back4app

Till now I was using back4app database for my flutter application. But now I want to migrate my data to another database.

So rest all the data has been transferred but **I am not able to find a way to retrieve user password from the user class as it is a hidden field by default**.

Kindly let me know if there is any way to retrieve hidden fields in back4pp database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to export users' passwords in plain text as it would be a security vulnerability. You can export the hashes in the case it helps.

Comment: Could you please tell, how to export hashes of the user passwords and how to decrypt those hashes so I can store them as plain text in another database?

Comment: In order to export the hashes you can connect to the MongoDB and dump the data. But like I told you before there is no way to decrypt the passwords into plain text. You can use same algorithm Parse Server uses to verify user input passwords though.